# Spring Boot 1.5.2.RELEASE database backed sessions

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-session

I am working on a project using Spring Boot 1.5.2.RELEASE and have been tasked with adding database backed HTTP sessions.

So, I got this working in the 2.0.0.RELEASE easily enough and the application started and created the tables *spring_session* and *spring_session_attributes*

Here's the properties I added to the later version that got things working:

```
spring.session.store-type=jdbc
spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=ALWAYS
```

Looking at spring-boot 1.5.2.RELEASE it seems to use spring-session 1.3.0.RELEASE as the managed version so I found the docs here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html5/guides/httpsession-jdbc.html

No matter what I try I get the following error:

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
>   /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback. Tue Mar 20 14:02:06 GMT
>   2018 There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error,
>   status=500). PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT
>   S.SESSION_ID, S.CREATION_TIME, S.LAST_ACCESS_TIME,
>   S.MAX_INACTIVE_INTERVAL, SA.ATTRIBUTE_NAME, SA.ATTRIBUTE_BYTES FROM
>   SPRING_SESSION S LEFT OUTER JOIN SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES SA ON
>   S.SESSION_ID = SA.SESSION_ID WHERE S.SESSION_ID = ?]; nested exception
>   is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "spring_session"
>   does not exist Position: 127

Here is my application.properties (I am trying to get the tables to appear in my PostgreSQL database)- these tables should be created for me automatically, right?

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sandbox
spring.datasource.password=sandbox
spring.datasource.username=sandbox
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.template.cache=false
spring.session.store-type=jdbc
spring.session.jdbc.initializer.enabled=true
```

Comment: Do you by any chance use multiple data sources in your app? If not, could you put together a [minimal, complete, and verifiable sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Does `sandbox` have alteration permissions on your Db? I guess it has..

Comment: Can you add this to your cfg? `spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I couldn’t get the tables to create automatically so I dug through the spring-session jar file for the schema and created them manually. Good news is that sessions are now persisted in my database!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try after adding this
spring.session.jdbc.table-name=SPRING_SESSION

Comment: thanks, same problem I'm afraid: ERROR: relation "spring_session" does not exist Position: 127